# Expo.dev settings bodyParser limit to solve PayloadTooLargeError, but where and how?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have some **sometimes** issues with handling large datasets with Expo.

```
at App.js:264:4 in handleNewEventOfApp
at App.js:1813:18 in setTimeout$argument_0
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/middleware/remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware.ts:31:3)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at serveStatic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/middleware/remoteDevtoolsCorsMiddleware.ts:31:3)
    at call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
    at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
    at serveStatic (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
```

I found out that it can be solved by setting a larger limit to the bodyParser of JSON and extend it. Should be as easy as adding something like this: `app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));`

But where and how does this work in Expo with React-Native? I don't see any place where to configure this.

Anyone?

Comment: That looks like something you'd use in Express on the backend.

Comment: Any solution yet?